# Problem with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, response

How do I get the $( data.id ) to become my element? At the moment it evaluates it to an int, not a tag with an specified id. I have tracked it all down to this problem, everything is the correct value according to FireBug until this point.

```
function editWinner( value, id )
{
    new Ajax.Request( 'ajax_edit_winner.php',
    {
        method: 'get',
        parameters: {
            value: value,
            id: id
        },
        onSuccess: function( response ) {
            var data = response.responseText.evalJSON();
            $( data.id ).setAttribute('onclick', 'editWinner( ' + !data.value + ', ' + data.id + ' )');
            $( data.id ).update( data.value );
        },
        onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `$` is provided by some library, but there are several that use that variable and they do different things with it. What library are you using? (Oh, and don't `setAttribute` on event handlers, use something that abstracts addEventListener (and the Microsoft equiv) and do it properly. (Also make use of the CODE formatting button that the Stack Overflow editor provides)

Comment: I'm using prototype, and sorry for the formatting. How do I do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see this is Prototype (sorry) I'd suggest trying either

- `$('' + data.id)` i.e. force the ID to be a string before passing it in.
- `$$('#' + data.id)` which is Prototype's selector syntax

Depending on your JSON parser the ID might be a string already. Beyond that I'm not sure what to suggest.

---

Old answer:

To select a tag you need `$('#tagId')`, i.e. a hash prefix on the ID. Without it's looking for a tag of the given type, e.g. `$('div')` to find div tags. [CSS selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors)

i.e. you probably want `$('#' + data.id)`

Comment: Yes, that seems more right, defining the id, but still not working...
this is my tag
<a onclick="editWinner( false, 264 )" href="#" id="264">Nej (Markera)</a>

Comment: You're suggesting jQuery-style syntax here, when the OP is using Prototype

Comment: @Gareth oops, you're right, I didn't recognise that as Prototype not jQuery. Take two.

Comment: $$( '#' + data.id ) was the way to go! still have to tweak the attribute.
Thanks for all help! =)